# Check if a string contains substring at the end

Tags: python, string, substring

I would like to check if a variable contains a substring at the end.

For example:

```
text = 'lord_of_pizzas_DFG'

if ???:
    print('You shall pass')
else:
    print('You shall not pass')
```

I want to know how to check if "DFG" is at the end of the string. What do I write instead of `???` to make the code print "You shall pass"?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`str.endswith`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm)

```
text = 'lord_of_pizzas_DFG'

if text.endswith("DFG"):
    print('You shall pass')
else:
    print('You shall not pass')
```

Comment: Also, `text[-3:]` if you want to explicitly say "last three characters".